# Solving simultaneos equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponentiation

I am new to simultaneous equations and need some help on this question:

> Solve
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>      x^{2 + 4y^2} &= 4 \\
>      y &= x - 1
> \end{align}
> $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think there are only numerical methods.

Substituting the 2nd expression into the first gives us

$$x^{2+4(x-1)^2} = 4$$

Taking $\ln$ on both sides gives us

$$(2+4(x-1)^2) \ln(x) - \ln(4) = 0$$

We now apply Newton-Raphson method. Let $f(x)$ denote the LHS. Thus,

$$f'(x) = 8(x-1)\ln(x) + \frac{1}{x} (2+4(x-1)^2)$$

For a starting value, let $x_0=1$. Thus,

$$\begin{align} 
x_1 &= x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}\\
&= 1 - \frac{f(1)}{f'(1)}\\
&= 1.693147181...\\
x_2 &= x_1 - \frac{f(x_1)}{f'(x_1)}\\
&= 1.693147181... - \frac{f(1.693147181...)}{f'(1.693147181...)}\\
&= 1.563497062...\\
x_3 &= x_2 - \frac{f(x_2)}{f'(x_2)}\\
&= 1.563497062... - \frac{f(1.563497062...)}{f'(1.563497062...)}\\
&= 1.545183059...\\
x_4 &= x_3 - \frac{f(x_3)}{f'(x_3)}\\
&= 1.545183059... - \frac{f(1.545183059...)}{f'(1.545183059...)}\\
&= 1.544847225...\\
x_5 &= x_4 - \frac{f(x_4)}{f'(x_4)}\\
&= 1.544847225... - \frac{f(1.544847225...)}{f'(1.544847225...)}\\
&= 1.544847114...\\
\end{align}$$

At this point, we have got a fairly good approximation for $x$, so we have $x=1.544847114...$, and $y=0.544847114...$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: plugging the equation $$y=x-1$$ in the first equation we get
$$x^{2+4(x-1)^2}=4$$
taking the logarithm on both sides we obtain:
$$(1+2(x-1)^2)\ln(x)=\ln(2)$$
can you go on?
one can also write $$x^{1+2y^2}=2$$ or $$x^{1+2y^2}=-2$$

Comment: please go it;s better you go on @Dr. Sonnhard , because i reached that step

Comment: i think we Need a numerical method to go further i have got this here

Comment: $$x = 1.544847114141373080677770618846802049647037780377832279464003202517687153498019631411342185755128902, y = .5448471141413730806777706188468020496470377803778322794640032025176871534980196314113421857551289024$$